# C++ Binary Tree Works in CentOS 6 but not Mac OSX Mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, centos

Right now I'm dumbfounded as to why the following program appears to work fine on my CentOS 6 box, but running the compiled program results in a Seg Fault 11 on my Mac OSX. I debug on my Macbook using Eclipse and the gdb debugger with some strange results. It's a simple binary tree example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "binary_tree.h"

using namespace std;

struct node* newNode(int x) {
        struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
        n->x = x;
        n->left = NULL;
        n->right = NULL;

        return n;
}

struct node* insert(struct node *node, int x) {
        if(node == NULL) {
                return newNode(x);
        } else {
                if(x <= node->x) {
                        node->left = insert(node->left, x);
                        cout << "INSERTED " << x << " LEFT OF " << node->x << endl;
                } else {
                        node->right = insert(node->right, x);
                        cout << "INSERTED " << x << " RIGHT OF " << node->x << endl;
                }

                return node;
        }
}

int main(void) {
        //Pointer to root node
        struct node *root = NULL;

        root = insert(root,4);
        root = insert(root,2);
        root = insert(root,3);
        root = insert(root,5);
        root = insert(root,1);
        root = insert(root,7);

        return 0;
}
```

And the header file:

```
/*
 * binary_tree.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jul 12, 2014
 *      Author: ccravens
 */

#ifndef BINARY_TREE_H_
#define BINARY_TREE_H_

struct node {
        int x;
        struct node *left;
        struct node *right;
};

#endif /* BINARY_TREE_H_ */
```

Any tips appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "Strange results" meaning that sometimes the program runs all the way through while debugging without the seg fault, and sometimes it doesn't. And sometimes the variables in the "Variables" in the variables view don't appear to be showing correct values, or in other words they don't show any value when they should be.

Comment: Don't call your variables the same name as your types.  You have `node` both as a parameter name and a type.  That just leads to confusion.  Second, why are you using the `struct` keyword where it is unneeded, and why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program instead of `new`?  Are you sure you're writing a C++ program instead of C program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

Should be:

```
struct node *n = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

You are allocating a pointer (8 bytes) rather than a struct node (24 bytes). Problems like this are easy to catch by executing your program under valgrind (www.valgrind.org).

Comment: Which goes to show, if the OP were writing C++ instead of C, that error more than likely would not have shown up.

Comment: And even easier to *avoid* if you size the allocation based on the size of the pointed-to rather than a type, i.e. `sizeof *n`. It still offers no haven for *arrays*, unfortunately, so diligence is needed regardless. Personally I'd `new node;`